# How to call PostgreSQL connection once using PyCharm?

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm, connection, psycopg2

I made a project using PyCharm and QT Designer and the database I used is PostgreSQL, all forms that is connected to database has the following codes:

```
*try:
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="admin",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="5432",
                              dbname="database")*
```

Is there any way(s) to call the connection once for all forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option, you could put the db connection code in a module and import that module in the forms

`connection.py`

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                          password="admin",
                          host="127.0.0.1",
                          port="5432",
                          dbname="database")
```

`form1.py`

```
 from yourproject.connection import connection
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 ...
```